# is it possible to place a box with text over a picture in latex beamer? using overpic and block

Tags: beamer, block, overpic

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % Transparente Overlays
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{multimedia} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\mode<beamer>{\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[absolute]{overpic}


\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth,tics=10,grid=true]
{intro2.pdf}
\put(0,40){\begin{block}{test1}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item understanding latex 
\end{itemize}
}
\end{block}} \end{overpic}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The answer is yes (if you use a minipage or something analogous). **EDIT**: Updated my beamer version, as recommended by @samcarter, and removed packages that are not directly relevant here.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % Transparente Overlays
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\mode<beamer>{\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]}
\usepackage[absolute]{overpic}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth,tics=10,grid=true]
{example-image-duck.pdf}
\put(0,40){\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{block}{test1}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item understanding latex 
\end{itemize}
}
\end{block}
\end{minipage}} 
\end{overpic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should consider updating your beamer version :)

Comment: Looks much better :)

Comment: @samcarter Agree. Do you know if there are any "nesting tikzpictures" issues if you put a beamer block in a `tikzpicture` node? After all, beamer loads all the pgf packages.

Comment: I have not yet encountered problems with using `tikzpicture`s in beamer blocks. I'd say as long as it works ... (the content of the block is usually well hidden from everything by a surrounding minipage)